# Verificar se um device possui GPS e Serviço de localização está ativo

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocalização

Preciso verificar se no iPad que estou usando possui GPS e se o serviço de localização do app esta ativo durante a utilização do app, como eu posso conseguir essas informações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando a classe [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) você pode utilizar o método [`locationServicesEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled), que é retornado um valor **BOOL**.

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // Localização não habilitada
}
```

Acredito que com isso você consiga o que quer.